# How can I differentiate between the past indefinite and the past perfect?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

How can I differentiate between the past indefinite and the past perfect?  What is the difference between the following examples?

1. I can't believe she ate my sandwich!
2. I couldn't believe she had eaten my sandwich!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't believe she ate my sandwich

Means that *she ate your sandwich* and *now you can't believe it*.

> I couldn't believe she had eaten my sandwich

Means that she ate the sandwich and then you couldn't believe that. Both action(*she ate the sandwich* and *you couldn't believe it*) happened in the past but the action "*she ate the sandwich*" happened before the other action "*you couldn't believe it*".